# JPA Desktop application

Tags: swing, jpa, jndi

I am developing a Java SWING application using JPA, I got much experience with JPA with Java EE,
But in this case i want to modify 'persistence.xml' values in running time. this can be done in Java EE using JNDI on application server, but in swing application I didn't found any solution for that

note: persistence.xml contains following properties

```
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/adlbprod?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
</properties>
```

its relay appreciated anybody can help this..
thanks

Comment: not really a swing question - basically, you need to find out how-to do it without an application server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all, 
I found the answer. how to modify the property at run time 
 {step 1 remove the properties want to load dynamically }

```
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/adlbprod?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
</properties>
```

{Step 2 create a Map for holds property value }

```
 Map pmap = new HashMap();
    pmap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "123");
    pmap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "root");
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPAQueryPU",pmap);

    try {

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(pmap);
        Map<String, Object> properties = emf.getProperties();
        System.out.println("pro"+properties);


        Batch ct = new Batch();
        EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        ct.setDescription("Test Batch");

        em.persist(ct);
        transaction.commit();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Note :- "JPAQueryPU" is name of the persistence unit

Thanks R+

Comment: newly added property values can load in external XML file.