# Define JPA configuration from external source

Tags: java, jpa

I'm using JPA quite often in command line java applications. With an application server I can easily link to an external configuration via `<jta-data-source>jdbc/myDatabase</jta-data-source>` in the `persistence.xml`. How is that possible **without an application server**? I could find some information about the attribute `<non-jta-data-source/>`. But how can I reference the values from an external file (probably in the properties format) in an elegant way? It would be nice to have as few as possible boilerplate code.

I've found an approach to this here, but I think there is a more elegant way:
[JPA Desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398108/jpa-desktop-application)

Comment: just because you have no app server doesn't mean you have no JTA. There are stand-alone JTA providers. You can also use JDBC URL/driver etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Now I'm working with this solution:

I need a properties file which looks like this:

```
javax.persistence.jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database
javax.persistence.jdbc.user = root
javax.persistence.jdbc.password = root
javax.persistence.jdbc.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Respecting this scheme allows me to use the values without any mapping later. I can then pass the values easily to cretae the EntityManagerFactory like this:

```
try (final InputStream jpaFileInput = Files.newInputStream(propFile)) {
    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(jpaFileInput);
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PU_NAME, properties);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to use JPA with desktop applications. It's almost the same thing but you will need to manage transactions. As you have no application server the management of each and every transaction has to be done by you. Access to your JPA unit can be achieved through EntityManagerFactory.

Example:

```
EntityManagerFactory emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpa-example");
EntityManager em = emFactory.getEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(address);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

You need to put your **persistence.xml file under META-INF** folder. You need to point out in your persistence config file that transaction type is **RESOURCE_LOCAL**. This is needed for running independently with no Application Server:

```
<persistence-unit name="jpa-example" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

You will however need to download and link the libraries in your project classpath. You will need the JTA jar and your persistence provider JARs which could be of Hibernate or any other vendor of your choosing. This could be achieved cleanly with Maven.

You may want to check this tutorial: 
http://java.dzone.com/articles/jpa-tutorial-setting-jpa-java

Comment: doesn't seem to be JPA that the OP mentions

Comment: Hibernate is an implementation of JPA spec.

Comment: I dont't want to stick with a certain implementation.

Comment: You may want to check the link provided in end of the answer.

Comment: Hibernate IS an implementation of JPA BUT you are proposing NOT USING JPA. You could just as easily update your answer with the equivalent USING JPA.

Comment: Sorry I was not proposing not to use, only that I used Hibernate directly to achieve it quickly. I have updated my answer to show the JPA equivalent.